# Azure devops pipelines - shared complex data between runs and different pipelines

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, azure-pipelines, user-management

I'm looking to execute some integration tests using CloudTestAgentTask@4, however these tests require a user. I do however want to avoid using the same user for every run because these runs can be done in parallel (multiple runs of the same pipeline, other pipelines executing some of the same tests etc). I was wondering if there is a feature that allows for complex data sharing, idealy something that also helps with sync issues when different runs try to interact with this entity. Something like the vm agent pool but sharing data instead?